# Windows Forms in Unmanaged Code?

Tags: .net, c++, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I find myself annoyed that Visual Studio comes with a fancy GUI interface designer and that it is only accessible to .NET applications and not even managed C++.

Is there any easy way to at least open up a C DLL type interface with unmanaged/foreign code?

Comment: As to the annoyance - you know, You don't have to use the designer if you don't like it.

Comment: I'm more annoyed at the fact that they have such a nice designer I can't use.

Comment: you *can*... or are you talking about the xaml stuff (not windows forms)

Answer (score 4):

Windows Forms is very much a part of the .NET framework and cannot be accessed (at least not in any practical sense) from unmanaged code. However, it is possible to call it from managed C++ (I don't know about designer support in Visual Studio itself, but managed C++ can definitely use the Windows Forms library).

You might want to look into other C++ GUI options, such as [Qt](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/), [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/), or [Gtkmm](http://www.gtkmm.org/).

Answer (score 3):

MFC is still a viable option for developing GUIs in Visual C++ 2008. Here is even a sample on [how to integrate MFC with WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms239720.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Managed C++ via Visual Studio has supported a forms designer since at least 2003 [C++ with managed Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983522(VS.71).aspx) and C++/CLI projects allow use of the forms designer, here's a quick [hello world](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/hellocli_part1.aspx) example to help you find it.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a will there is a way. If you are willing to jump through the hoops you can mix and match almost any combination of managed/unmanaged code.

Here is a nice (albeit old) overview:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973872.aspx